# Style on Request URL

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I've been noticing some weird requests on the webserver's event viewer, including CSS styles, HTML elements. Example:

[image]

The technologies used are asp.net webforms with routing, bundles for both css and javascript.

Can this be related to routing or just bad user input?

PS: no broken links on website. they all work fine and I can't replicate the issue.

Any ideas of what might me happening?

Comment: What happens if you search your code for `width: 150px !important; height: 140px`? Do you get any hits? I would start here, and see if there is any bad html somewhere.